# jquery div equal to window height stretches with content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the my contents `div height` equal to the `window.height - (footer.height + header.height)`. I also made the contents `overflow-y to scroll`.
This works perfectly unless the content inside the div exceeds the height limit the div stretches more then its height instead of going to scroll mode, can some one please tell me what am I missing here? thanks in advance!

```
$("#p_body").height($(window).height() - ($("#p_header").height() + $("#p_footer").height()) );
$("#content_body").height($("#p_body").height() - ($("#content_header").height() + 10) );
```

page structure:

```
<div id="p_header"></div>
<div id="p_body">
<div id="content_header"></div>
<div id="content_body" style="overflow-y:scroll;"></div>
</div>
<div id="p_footer"></div>
```

Comment: Im not seeing your problem does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7T8vL/) work how you want it to?

Comment: It does work unless the content i put in the body is longer then the window height,in this case the content_body stretches, I want it to stay the same height all the time and scroll thorught the cntent inside it.

Comment: I agree with Kyle. If you want the scrollable area to be smaller then you have to include that in your calculations or give the scrollable area a hard height value.  The code you gave us works as intended, especially when we add content: http://jsfiddle.net/zyV3W/1/.

Comment: Hey thank you guys, Apperently becouse i didnt have a height set in style at all it didnt see it as a fixed height, so write it as an answer if you want! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the problem was I had to set **any** fixed height value to my content div, as such:

```
<div id="p_header"></div>
<div id="p_body">
<div id="content_header"></div>
<div id="content_body" style="overflow-y:scroll; **height:10px;**"></div>
</div>
<div id="p_footer"></div>
```

Otherwise the code worked fine until the content inside the div exeeded the window.height() so it didnt see the content divs height as a fixed height.